# How to find list of adverbs with their usage related to corresponding verbs and adjectives

Tags: discussion

I am a Programmer and working on a NLP project that suggest adverbs to the adjectives and verbs in the sentence. I need grammar suggestion regarding this.

If anyone can tell the way or resource to find the words list and their corresponding adverbs that can be used with that word.

for example: Like I have time related words, whenever user inputs a sentence and I see a verb or adjective that is related to time, I suggest to him the adverb list that can be used with time.

So, I want to cover all that categories be it time, speed, linking adverbs, commonly used adverbs, etc. So I want to first have type of words and corresponding adverbs list.

Comment: You'd think ELU would be exactly the place for this kind of resource request, but I think you'll have better luck over at [stackoverflow.se] where they commonly have resource requests for NLP. You may even want to try [ell.se]. This is not to say that someone might answer here, just that there are other options too. Also, in the course of your research for these resources, if you find something, make sure to self-answer here, which would help people finding this question later.